# How can I sort Firestore stream based on timestamp in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, sorting, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am trying to generate a list using stream builder in flutter and want to sort that list based on firestore timestamp. I have already tried this code given below

````
```stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection("posts")
                      .doc(widget.eid)
                      .collection("users")
                      .orderBy("postDate", descending: true)
                      .where("ownerId", isEqualTo: user.userId)
                      .snapshots(),```
````

and the error i got is: "The query requires an index. You can create it here:"

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this issue by adding indexing on firestore

Comment: Would you care to add a link to adding indexing on firestore? Or better yet summarize your solutions here?

Comment: for newbies (me). i couldn't build the index in firestore correctly, so went to firebase project / cloud firestore / indexes, deleted what was there, ran the code, and vs code gave me exact url to biuld the index in the way the code needed it.

Answer (score 1):

i think you making two mistake first you useing ordey by before where thats a wrong way to use the **where** so put where first and then use order by and second your first collection field should not empty if its empty thsts shows italic so you cant fetch data. according firestore its means its delted by defalut. so i make a correction in query.

`stream:FirebaseFirestore.instnce.collection("posts") .doc(widget.eid) .collection("users") .where("ownerid",isEqualto:user.userId) .orderBy("postdate",decsending:true) .snapshots(),`

Comment: Thanks, Muhammad the issue is resolved using indexing in firestore